# Need simple Rails many to many association logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a list of products and a list of categories. Also I have a mapping table `product_categories` which tells that products come under different categories and also category has many products. Here the category list is defined by admin. The number of categories is fixed, but can be varied. Now I need to get the list of products which are mapped with categories

```
product.rb
has_many :product_categories, dependent: :destroy
has_many :categories, through: :product_categories

category.rb
has_many :product_categories
has_many :products, :through => :product_categories

product_category.rb
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :category
```

I have written the code as:

```
ProductCategory.joins(:category).map(&:category).uniq
```

Is there any way to simplify this line?

Comment: Do you need a list of categories, that have at least one product (like in your code), product count by category or products themselves in categories?

Comment: yes i need the list of categories that have at least one product. Not the count. I need the entire record(s) @Vasfed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of categories that have products you can use SQL `inner join`, which is the default in rails.

```
Category.joins(:product_categories).distinct
```

Comment: I think this will speed up the execution as it uses two joins `("SELECT DISTINCT 'categories'.* FROM 'categories' INNER JOIN 'product_categories' ON 'product_categories'.'category_id' = 'categories'.'id' INNER JOIN 'domains' ON 'domains'.'id' = 'product_categories'.'product_id'")`, whereas the previous one uses only one join `("SELECT DISTINCT 'categories'.* FROM 'categories' INNER JOIN 'product_categories' ON 'product_categories'.'category_id' = 'categories'.'id'")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Category.joins(:products).distinct
```

Comment: Execution takes more time than 'Category.joins(:products).distinct'. I have checked both the execution time. For 'Category.joins(:products).distinct', it takes 5ms and for your query, its 9ms. Could be better if its possible to reduce the execution time much more.

Comment: What you want to say?? Category.joins(:products).distinct is taking more time or less??

Comment: Its taking more time.